# symfony2 cache is not clearing even deleted cache folder

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to get changes in twig file on web page. There is some cache problem with symfony2. Cache is not being clear unless deleting app/cache folder. 
Please help to solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: also run cache clear command but not effective.

Comment: Edit your post to show the `EXACT` command you used.

Answer (score 1):

Disable twig cache, edit config.yml:

```
twig:
    cache: false
```

Comment: Also tried that still not being clear